# Is there any way to implement early stopping callback for Tensorflow 2 model_main_tf.py?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Hello I'm working on object detection using tensorflow 2 object detection API model_main_tf2.py file normally we can use early stopping callback for model.fit() when we use normally but when i tried to training with pipeline config model_main_tf2.py file and .config file I'm not able to implement it because I'm unable to locate model.fit() in the main file so please is there any way i can implement the early stopping for model_main_tf2.py file please help me.

Link to the file: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, you should add, at least, a link to the file for us to understand

Comment: @ClaudiaR Thanks for giving advice I'm new to this so please help me https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py this is the link for the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look inside the `model_main_tf2.py` [file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/d3bd8c0d535783c6cd9d676aaf0b1ba8d869b9c9/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py#L105). Let's take the following piece of code:

```
model_lib_v2.train_loop(
          pipeline_config_path=FLAGS.pipeline_config_path,
          model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
          train_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps,
          use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu,
          checkpoint_every_n=FLAGS.checkpoint_every_n,
          record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
```

Instead of executing the training through `fit` it is used a custom training loop. In the code above is called the function that executes the training operation. `model_lib_v2` is just another [file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/d3bd8c0d535783c6cd9d676aaf0b1ba8d869b9c9/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py) of the repo that you've linked.

If you have a look at the `train_loop` function, you'll see that at some point is executed the following code:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    losses_dict, _ = _compute_losses_and_predictions_dicts(
        detection_model, features, labels,
        training_step=training_step,
        add_regularization_loss=add_regularization_loss)

    losses_dict = normalize_dict(losses_dict, num_replicas)

  trainable_variables = detection_model.trainable_variables

  total_loss = losses_dict['Loss/total_loss']
  gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, trainable_variables)
```

[GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) basically computes the gradients needed to update the weights of the model during the training phase. I won't go into much details, but if you are interested you can have a look at the linked documentation.

Now, you are interested in adding an early stopping callback, but you don't have a `fit`. You can still add early stopping, but in a different way.

You can follow a strategy like the one below (Refer to this tutorial by [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/early_stopping?hl=en#tensorflow_2_early_stopping_with_a_custom_training_loop) for the full code):

```
epochs = 100
patience = 5  # you can play with this values to obtain the best config
wait = 0
best = 0
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # training (calling the function that holds the GradientTape
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(ds_train):
      loss_value = train_step(x_batch_train, y_batch_train)
    
    # updating the metrics after the whole training loop on a single epoch         
    train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
    train_loss = train_loss_metric.result()
    train_acc_metric.reset_states()
    train_loss_metric.reset_states()
    print("Training acc over epoch: %.4f" % (train_acc.numpy()))
    
    # evaluating the model just trained in a new epoch, on the validation data
    for x_batch_val, y_batch_val in ds_test:
      test_step(x_batch_val, y_batch_val)
    
    # updating the metrics for validation
    val_acc = val_acc_metric.result()
    val_loss = val_loss_metric.result()
    val_acc_metric.reset_states()
    val_loss_metric.reset_states()
    print("Validation acc: %.4f" % (float(val_acc),))
    print("Time taken: %.2fs" % (time.time() - start_time))

    # The early stopping strategy: stop the training if `val_loss` does not
    # decrease over a certain number of epochs.
    wait += 1
    if val_loss > best:
      best = val_loss
      wait = 0
    if wait >= patience:
      break
```

Comment: i got confused with in which file i should add this code like in model_lib_v2.py file or model_main_tf2.py file can you help me @ClaudiaR

Comment: Probably inside model_lib_v2, find a place where the performances are evaluated  (it is computed val_loss or something similar), and add the check val_loss > best ...